# How to return a single object with Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a single object with profile information but am stuck getting an array in return. How do I just return a single object.

Current output:

```
[{"id":1,"username":"someusername"}]
```

Desired output:

```
{"id":1,"username":"someusername"}
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')
```

views.py

```
# from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from profiles.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
# Create your views here.


class CurrentUserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Lists information related to the current user.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user.id
        return User.objects.filter(id=user)
```

Comment: What if you query the endpoint with the `/<id>/` suffix (with `<id>` replaced with an id, for example `1`, so something like `localhost:8000/api/user/1`?

Answer (score 11):

The normal usage is use `/user/` to get a list,use `/user/[user_id]/` to get a certain object.
If you want `/user/` return detail info,do as:

```
class CurrentUserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Lists information related to the current user.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = request.user
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Though I ended up using a different solution this did in fact work. I chose the other solution (posted on this thread) as it didn't require additional imports.

Comment: @Tantivy Hello, friend. Can you share with me what is the 'other solution'?(If you remember yet XD)

Comment: This is a really bad approach especially when the single object that you want to return is specifically the current users user profile... Especially when you want to have some fields non-read only. The idea that you are even exposing the concept of multiple profiles is a security smell.

Comment: yes, i said it's not the normal way